# Dynamically adding more values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dictionary, data-structures, dynamic

How can I dynamically add more values in the sets defined as follows in Javascript:

```
var data1 = [
    { name: 'S1', elems: [0, 1, 2] },
    { name: 'S2', elems: [1, 2, 3] },
    { name: 'S3', elems: [0, 2, 4] },
  ];
```

What I want to do is similar to the following:

```
    (key, value) = read_a_row_from_table_of_values;
    if (key is present in data1) // could be by iterating all the keys in data 
    {
       data1[key][elems].push(value); // this is the point of concern (how to push values)
    }
```

As I am feeding this data to another tool (UpSet), so this data structure (in the form of name and elems) has to be followed. Details about that can be found [here](https://github.com/upsetjs/upsetjs/blob/7d633bd52e7f5d106458481ab644c3e97b44bc06/packages/model/src/data/asSets.ts#L84).

Comment: `data1` is an `Array`, not a `Map` or `object` so it cannot have "keys" - so please clarify what you mean by "`if( key is present in data1 )` ?

Comment: yeah, what would a key be? and are names unique?

Comment: key is name (S1 lets say)

Comment: What is the hard part? If you just wrote out the pseudo code you have in JS, you've your solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only ever adding 1 or 2 items (i.e. such that `O(n)` insert time is acceptable) then this solution (based on @mplungjan's now-deleted comment) should work for you:

```
var data1 = [
    { name: 'S1', elems: [0, 1, 2] },
    { name: 'S2', elems: [1, 2, 3] },
    { name: 'S3', elems: [0, 2, 4] },
  ];

function add( data1, name, value ) {
    const exists = data1.find( e => e.name === name );
    if( exists ) {
        exists.elems.push( value );
    }
    else {
        data1.push( { name, elems: [value] } );
    }
}

add( data1, 'S4', 1 );
add( data1, 'S3', 2 );
add( data1, 'S5', 3 );
```

If you'll be performing *mass* operations on `data1` then you should convert it to a `Map` first (note that `Array.prototype.map` and `Map<K,V>` are completely different things):

```
function convertData1ToMap( data1 ) {
    const m = new Map();
    for( const e of data1 ) {
        m.set( e.name, e.elems );
    }
    return m;
}

function convertMapToData1( m ) {
    const arr = [];
    for( const k of map.keys() ) {
        const elems = map.get( k );
        arr.push( { name: k, elems } );
    }
    return arr;
}

//

const m = convertData1ToMap( data1 );

// Mass insert:

for( let i = 4; i < 10 * 1000; i++ ) {
    
    const name = 'S' + i.toString();
    if( m.has( name ) ) {
        m.get( name ).push( i );
    }
    else {
        m.set( name, [i]);
    }
}

// Recreate `data1`:

data1 = convertMapToData1( m );
```

Comment: @mplungjan Because `Array.prototype.find` returns `undefined` if there are no matches.

Comment: nice idea to use Map there

Answer (score 0):

Entries and [Find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) will work

Basically

```
data1.find(elem => elem.name===key).elems.push(value)
```

We can alas not do a oneliner if the newValues may contain a key not in the data1 array

```js
const data1 = [
    { name: 'S1', elems: [0, 1, 2] },
    { name: 'S2', elems: [1, 2, 3] },
    { name: 'S3', elems: [0, 2, 4] },
  ];
const newValues = {"S1": 4,"S2":5, "S6": 6 }

Object.entries(newValues)
  .forEach(([key, value]) => {
    const found = data1.find(elem => elem.name === key);
    if (found) found.elems.push(value);
  });
console.log(data1);
```

If you want to merge, you need to add missing keys

```js
const data1 = [
    { name: 'S1', elems: [0, 1, 2] },
    { name: 'S2', elems: [1, 2, 3] },
    { name: 'S3', elems: [0, 2, 4] },
  ];
const newValues = {"S1": 4,"S2":5, "S6": 6 }

Object.entries(newValues)
  .forEach(([key, value]) => {
    const found = data1.find(elem => elem.name === key);
    if (found) found.elems.push(value);
    else data1.push({name:key,elems: [value]});
  })
console.log(data1);
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't work if a value should be added to a `name` that doesn't exist in `data1`.